# Laravel Cache is returning old values

Tags: php, laravel, caching

```
$value = Cache::remember('test', 1, function() {
  return 'Jabra2';
});
```

This is just a sample code. It should return 'Jabra2' in $value. But, on my production, though it's set to 1 minute, it is still return old value 'Jabra'.

Any idea why it's happening ? (I am using file cache)

Answer (score 1):

The second argument is seconds, not minutes. You're setting the cache to expire after 1 second.

It used to be minutes up to 5.7, but was changed in 5.8.

The recommended way is to not use integers but a Carbon instance:

```
Cache::remember('test', now()->addMinute(), function() { ... });
```

Docs on the change: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#cache-ttl-in-seconds

Comment: It's not what I asked